# Android Studio: How to start an own activity/app when a selected app (Any app) is started?

Tags: android, kotlin, system, broadcast, foreground-service

for an app, i am trying to program, i need to be able to react to the event of the user starting any app on his device. I then want to select if the started app is the one i want to react to in my app. After the start of an app i want to launch a activity from my app.

I already searched a lot, i already tried this, but please prove me wrong:

- Broadcast Events dont have this function to send an event if any app starts, and i dont want to look if every app may produces a broadcast event such as this itself
- WorkManager doesnt work because it would need to run the wole time the device is on
- Services () may work, but i havent found a way on how to implement something like that, the service needs to be started when the device is started and cant stop (With ActivityManager you can at least see the current processes and which app is in front)

Are there any other possibilities to catch such an event or notice it in a simple way?

Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, this is not possible, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: It is possible, there is this app called "zario" which already does it, if you open a app which you have selected first, "zario" pops up, i looked at the processes that are running whilst having this app installed, it seems like its using also a service